# Django ModelForm not saving NULL values

Tags: python, django, model, django-forms

I've looked all around the documentation and internet, but I can't find an answer for this. I have a model with several fields that have (blank=True, null=True). When I save the ModelForm, the columns get set as empty strings in the database. I would like it to save them as NULL in the database (if they are empty).

How can I tell ModelForm to save empty values as NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is by design. Django would rather have empty strings than NULLs, for various reasons. Google will tell you, but long story short, Django finds `NULL` and `""` overlapping in meaning, and does away with the former.

What you **can** do, is intercept the value coming from the database driver and change empty strings to `NULL` and the other way round. Implementing a custom `CharField` subclass will get you there.

In doing so, you'll experience the ambiguity between `NULL` and `""` for yourself :).